# Will this character get back his Infinity Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, as all the stones were returned to their timeline, will Doctor Strange have the time stone now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes and no.

Since all the stones are returned back to their original time and place in the end, everything will go as they were. Dr. Strange will come to Sanctum, meet the Ancient One, become Sorcerer Supreme, and possess the time stone.

However, he will not have the Time Stone after the events of Endgame cause they are destroyed already.

Comment: Plus the ability to literally stop and rewind time kind of trivialises any encounter he has so they need to keep it gone to make the next Dr Strange movie intereting.