# What will Doctor Strange protect now?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, doctor-strange

We learn in the movies *Doctor Strange* (2016) and *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018) that all sorcerers including Doctor Strange have sworn an oath to protect the Time Stone at any cost. But in the concluding scenes of *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), Captain America returns all the Stones in their past, which means Doctor Strange and Sanctum Sanctorum in the present do not possess​ the Time Stone anymore; so what will they be protecting now?

Given the importance of Time Stone, will Doctor Strange no longer need it to fight enemies unknown? Doctor Strange used it to defeat Dormammu which would have been very difficult without the Time Stone.

Comment: Related: [What happens to the Time Stone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100000/what-happens-to-the-time-stone), as well as [Will this character get back his Infinity Stone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99803/49) and [Given what happens in Endgame, why doesn't Dormammu come back to attack the universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99849/49)

Comment: Stark: What do you do? Strange: Protecting your reality, douchebag!

Comment: He's going to be protecting Earth - which presumably will be under series threat now that it no longer has any of the stones.

Comment: Why would the Ancient One not pass the Eye (containing the Time Stone) to her designated successor, Dr Strange, once Cap has returned the Stone to her?

Comment: @Vishwa beat me to it!

Comment: @mpez0 She did, five years later, which was six years before the present, where the Time Stone was destroyed five years earlier.

Comment: also if I remember correctly the Sanctorum  has a lot of other artifacts which may be valuable

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles protection of the earth won't be depending on stones IMO, I believe Sorcerer Supreme'll have more tricks under his arsenal..\ the greatest threat came from dude wearing stones isn't it?

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe-Levi um... yay! ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Time Stone ain't the only thing in this world that needs protection. Sure, it was a big deal to protect it while it was here, but it's not the *only* thing wizards do.

Remember that in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Strange explains to Thor that part of his role is to protect the Earth from intergalactic/interdimensional threats, Loki being one.

> STRANGE: So, I keep a watch list of individuals and beings from other realms that may be a threat to this world. Your adopted brother, Loki, is one of those beings.
>
> THOR: He's a worthy inclusion.

If decades of comics and sci-fi movies have taught us anything, it's that there will *always* be an alien race ready to wage war on us and/or mystic entities craving for whatever power might be found on Earth . Sure, the Time Stone is a powerful weapon, but that's not the only thing Strange has at his disposal.

And if you've seen the post-credits scene of *Doctor Strange*, you have a hint of what he will be protecting next. Namely...

> Himself, and other sorcerers, as Mordo is headed towards his comic book history of killing/depowering sorcerers.

Comment: Wong in IW leaves Banner to protect the Sanctum because it is unguarded.

Comment: Also Stark and Strange's interactions in IW give some good insight with the "protecting reality" quote etc.